# How to revert changes in the working directory only

Tags: git

I have a broken merge and I want to revert changes in the working directory to find out where it's broken.  I want to preserve the index so I can add the fixes to it and eventually check them in. Essentially, I want the working directory to be the same as the HEAD but without modifying the index.  This essentially would apply a reverse patch based on the index to the working directory. It seems like this would be the opposite of a `git reset`.

How do you do this in git?

Answer (score 6):

You could commit the index, reset the working directory, and then reset the commit.

```
$ git commit -m "blah"
$ git reset --hard
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
```

**Edit:**  It seems I misunderstood the original question.

To reset the working tree to HEAD without disturbing the index, do the following:

```
$ git checkout -- .
$ git diff --cached | git apply --reverse
```

(And it looks like @Brice already gave this answer.)

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: You misunderstood both input conditions and requirements for output. On enter, there should  be no modification between the index and the working tree (or at least assumed that the user can deal with them for himself). So 'M' is assumed only in the first column. On exit, you need to revert the working tree to **HEAD** but keep the index intact. This is indicated by 'M' present in both columns of `git status --short` output, with the additional requirement that `git diff HEAD` output should be empty.

Comment: OP said, "I want to revert changes in the working directory... I want the working directory to be the same as the HEAD but without modifying the index."  OP wants to reset changes to the working directory without modifying the index.  This clearly implies that there are changes in the working directory.  "without modifying the index" implies that there are also staged changes in the index.  This solution resets the working directory to HEAD while leaving the index unchanged.  I'm failing to see why you think this is wrong.

Comment: "This clearly implies that there are changes in the working directory." Yes, but these changes are assumed to be between **HEAD** and working tree (WT), not between **Index** and WT. "implies that there are also staged changes in the index" - this is right and, moreover, is necessary. However, your solution reverts WT to Index, which is already equal to WT, that's why I've said that it does nothing.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're getting at.  The changes in the working tree (`git diff`) should be the inverse of those in the index (`git diff --cached`).

Answer (score 5):

I was looking at a simple command doing the same thing but there is none.
Though you stated the proper way to do so in your question:

> This essentially would apply a reverse patch based on the index to the working directory.

So the answer is pretty simple:

```
git diff --no-color --staged | git apply --reverse
```

So no need to commit anything, simply apply the reverse of your index.

Note that if some changes in the working dir are not staged/in the index, they won't be reversed this way.

If you want to revert everything in the working directory (even the changes not indexed and new files as well) except the index itself, run the following before:

```
git stash save --include-untracked --keep-index
```

You can drop it afterwards if you don't intend to reuse it:

```
git stash drop
```

If you want to revert everything except the untracked files (new files not in the index)
Do before:

```
git checkout .
```

To summarize here are few bash functions:

```
function git-unapply-index {
    git diff --no-color --staged | which git apply --reverse
}

function git-revert-workdir-keep-untracked {
    git checkout .
    git-unapply-index
}

function git-revert-workdir-all {
    git stash save --include-untracked --keep-index
    git stash drop
    git-unapply-index
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reverse patch can be generated for the existing commits, not for the changes in the index.

1. Commit the changes in the index [may be in diff branch].
2. Execute `git revert -n <commit>`

It will generate the reverse patch in your working directory for your commit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `git checkout <commit>`?

Fragment of `git help checkout`:

```
git checkout [<branch>], git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>], git checkout [--detach] [<commit>]
       This form switches branches by updating the index, working tree, and HEAD to reflect the specified branch or commit.

       If -b is given, a new branch is created as if git-branch(1) were called and then checked out; in this case you can use the --track or --no-track
       options, which will be passed to git branch. As a convenience, --track without -b implies branch creation; see the description of --track below.

       If -B is given, <new_branch> is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of

           $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
           $ git checkout <branch>

       that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "git checkout" is successful.
```

Comment: Then as @Patric James McDougle said you need stash files before checkout.

Comment: Simply typing `git checkout` for me restores the file to what's in the index and does not remove the changes from the index.  Not sure why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: That's not what I want.  I want the index to be preserved but I want the working directory to be the same as HEAD.  This means that there would be a change in the index and the corresponding "backwards" change in the working directory.  I can do it manually but I have over 500 files to do this for so it will be tedious to do it one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking to `git stash`. With `git stash` you are able to make the working directory look just like HEAD and you can do anything else when you are in that state. Once you are done, you can `git stash pop` and get all of your changes back. You have to make sure you don't change the files that are stashed though, otherwise you'll have merge conflicts to resolve.

Comment: Doesn't quite do what I want.  It just reverts any changes in the working directory and stashes them.  For what I want, every modified file should be both in the index and locally modified in the working directory.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Things in the index have to be in the working directory. Why are you wanting to do this anyway? Can you not just `git commit` and then `git checkout HEAD~1`?

Comment: What will git checkout HEAD~1 checkout for a merge?  The following command shows how you can have a file changed in the index and in the working directory at the same time: mkdir foo; git init foo; cd foo; echo a > a; git add a; echo b >> a; git status

Comment: @StephenRasku Try `git checkout -- a`. I think that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you need:

```
git commit -m "Say thanks to John McClane"
git reset --hard HEAD^
git reset HEAD@{1} -- .
```

I assumed that you have staged all necessary files prior to doing this. Otherwise add the `-a` key to the first command or invoke *git-add* before it.

Note that `--` in the last command is optional, it was included for illustrative purposes only, to distinguish it from other forms of *git-reset*.